# Conditional expectation of continuous RV

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be random variable and $f$ it's density. How can one calculate $E(X\vert X<a)$?

From definition we have:

$$E(X\vert X<a)=\frac{E\left(X \mathbb{1}_{\{X<a\}}\right)}{P(X<a)}$$

Is this equal to:

$$\frac{\int_{\{X<a\}}xf(x)dx}{P(X<a)}$$

? If yes, then how one justify it? Thanks. I'm conditional expectation noob.

Also, what is $E(X|X=x_0)$? In discrete case it is $x_0$...

Comment: If $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a random variable then $\{X<a\}\subseteq\Omega$ (in general it is not a subset of $\mathbb R$) so $\int_{\{X<a\}}xf(x)dx$ should change into $\int^a_{-\infty}xf(x)dx$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\int_BXdP=\int_\Omega X1_BdP$. If $X$ has density $f$, this is equal to $\int x1_B(x)f(x)dx=\int_Bxf(x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Under condition $X<a$ you are "observing" the 'same' rv, but somehow it is 'forbidden' for $X$ to take values $\geq a$.

That asks for a PDF that maintains the quantitive relations when it comes to probabilities on subsets of $\{X<a\}$. We can start with naively taking a function equal to the original PDF on $(-\infty,a)$ and taking value $0$ on $[a,\infty)$. But this function is not a PDF because taking the integral over it we get $P(X<a)$ as value, and not $1$ as we should.

This is solved by dividing the function by $P(X<a)$. The new PDF is: $$\frac{f(x)1_{(-\infty,a)}(x)}{P(X<a)}$$